# How to find everyday collections in a month from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

```
Carts Table structure:
id , invoice_id, product_id, quantity , purchase_price, created_at, updated_at 

Invoices Table structure:
id, customer_id, discount, vat, created_at, updated_at
```

I was trying to find everyday total collections in a month from two above tables.
Here each voucher collection can be calculated as following way

```
static function totalPrice($id)
    {
        $itemsPrice = 0;
        $prices = DB::table('invoices')
                    ->join('carts','carts.invoice_id','invoices.id')
                    ->select('purchase_price','quantity')
                    ->where('carts.invoice_id','=',$id)
                    ->get();

        $invoice_price = DB::table('invoices')
                    ->select('vat','discount')
                    ->where('invoices.id','=',$id)
                    ->first();

        foreach ($prices as $price) 
        {
            $itemsPrice = $itemsPrice+ $price->purchase_price*$price->quantity;
        }

        $itemsPrice = $itemsPrice - $invoice_price->discount + (($itemsPrice*$invoice_price->vat)/100);

        return $itemsPrice;
    }
```

But problem is i wanted to calculated through query builder.

Expected output will be like this :

```
Today        Sum
01-01-2018   1200
02-01-2010   1100
03-01-2018   1200
04-01-2018   1030
```

And so on..

It doesn't give the proper output. But i need to solve it in this way. Thanks

```
  $monthly_report_chart = DB::table("invoices")
         ->select( DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%d/%m/%Y ') as today"),
                          DB::raw("SUM(collected_today) as sum") 
                        )
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(updated_at)'))
         ->whereMonth('updated_at','=',date('m'))
         ->get();
```

Comment: do you have different vat for each invoices ?

Comment: Yes, it could be

Comment: It would be some easier if you store the total amount in the invoices table, then with a simpler query (grouping by date) you'd have it ;)

Comment: I know it would be easy but the problem is quantity update is too frequently it's tough to maintain total amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check for **year** to get the correct, otherwise it will fetch result from other years too.

$itemsPrice is will be `SELECT SUM(purchase_price * quantity) AS price FROM carts WHERE carts.invoice_id = invoices.id`

we can get this result with:

```
$monthly_report_chart = DB::table("invoices")
         ->select( DB::raw("
            DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%d/%m/%Y ') AS date,
            SUM(
                    (
                        SELECT
                            SUM(purchase_price * quantity) AS price
                        FROM
                            carts
                        WHERE
                            carts.invoice_id = invoices.id
                    ) 
                    - discount 
                    + (
                        (
                            SELECT
                                SUM(purchase_price * quantity) AS price
                            FROM
                                carts
                            WHERE
                                carts.invoice_id = invoices.id
                        ) * vat / 100
                    )
            ) AS sum"))
         ->whereMonth('updated_at', '2')
         ->whereYear('updated_at', '2018')
         ->groupBy('date')
         ->get();
```

But we can improve the query, we should not fetch $itemsPrice twice in the query so lets do some math:

if `x = itemsPrice`, `y = discount` and `z = vat` then

```
Formula      x - y+((x * z)/100)
is equal to  ((x - y)100 + (x * z))/100
is equal to  (100x - 100y + x*z)/100
is equal to  (x(100+z) - 100y)/100
```

Since `x-y+((xz)/100)` is equal to `(x(100+z) - 100y)/100` then the query will be.

```
$monthly_report_chart = DB::table("invoices")
         ->select( DB::raw("
            DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%d/%m/%Y ') AS date,
            SUM(
                (
                    (
                        SELECT
                            SUM(purchase_price * quantity) AS price
                        FROM
                            carts
                        WHERE
                            carts.invoice_id = invoices.id
                    ) *(100 + vat) - 100 * discount
                ) / 100
            ) AS sum"))
         ->whereMonth('updated_at', '2')
         ->whereYear('updated_at', '2018')
         ->groupBy('date')
         ->get();
```

**PS**: I haven't tested it so please update me if something goes wrong.

Comment: There is mission of carts table joining in the query

Comment: Check again I'm doing that in `select`

Comment: Vat is % which should be added with total price - discount (not percentage).

Comment: Isn't this your formula? `itemsPrice - discount + ((itemsPrice * vat) / 100)`

Comment: Yes. While i implement your query it shows wrong answer. That's why I'm asking `- 100 * discount`  shouldn't be devided by 100

Comment: Here is the invoice table : https://ibb.co/b5FJ1o
Here is the cart table: https://ibb.co/ncMmnT

For 1st of july the output should be 4138.55 but from your solution output comes : 5931.5 

That's why i have confusion

Comment: Do you see any result difference between my both solutions? If, yes then I must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, though not tested

Subquery (calculate price group by invoice)

```
$sub = DB::table("invoices")
         ->join('carts','carts.invoice_id','invoices.id')
         ->select('vat', 'discount', DB::raw("SUM(purchase_price * quantity) as totalPrice"), 'updated_at')
         ->groupBy('invoices.id')
         ->whereMonth('updated_at','=',date('m'));
```

Calculate report using subquery

```
$reports = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
            ->select(
                      DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%d/%m/%Y ') as today"), 
                      DB::raw('($totalPrice - discount + (($totalPrice * vat)/100)) as sum')
                  )
            ->mergeBindings( $sub->getQuery() );
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(updated_at)'))
            ->get();
```

Read it

```
foreach($reports as $report){
    echo $report->today ." " . $report->sum;
}
```